# Зачем в Java потоки исполнения объединяются в группы?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Вот например

```
Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
System.out.println("Teкyщий поток исполнения : " + t );
```

выведет

```
Текущий поток исполнения : Thread[main,5,main]
```

где `main` имя главного потока по умолчанию, `5` это приоритет, `main` группа потоков исполнения, к которой относится данный поток.

Что представляет из себя группа потоков исполнения?
Зачем в Java потоки исполнения объединяются в группы?

Answer (score 2):

> Группа потоков исполнения - это структура данных, которая управляет
>   состоянием всего ряда потоков исполнения в целом.([стр 291](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31249554/))

Каждая группа потоков исполнения представляется объектом [класса](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html) `ThreadGroup`.

Группа потоков также может включать в себя другие группы потоков.

Группы потоков (`thread groups`) улучшают вопросы, связанные с управляемостью и безопасностью, а именно:

- Можно прервать работу сразу всех потоков группы.
- Установить для них единое максимальное значение приоритета выполнения.
- Наложить ограничения на способность потоков, принадлежащих группе, выполнять те или иные действия.

Comment: Интересно было бы узнать как добавить поток в группу и затем обратиться к нему через группу?